# How to add my proxy to well known proxy lists

Tags: networking, proxy

Where do open proxy lists such as hidemyass.com/proxy-list get their proxies from? Do they crawl for these proxies, or is there some hidden 'add proxy' button where you can manually add proxies?

Answer (score 0):

They scan for proxies. Noone in ones right mind wouldn't want to publish own server as open proxy. You may wan't to add your proxy to CODEEN list, but noone uses those, as they are monitored for everything, and if you are using proxy, in most cases, you don't want to be monitored.

Comment: Ok. But if they scan for proxies, and find some, how can they guarantee that these proxies are not monitoring the traffic? Do they assume that these proxies are misconfigured or something?